# Does the HTTP Response Stream need error event handlers In Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, marblejs

I tried many experiments but I could not get HTTP `OutgoingMessage` to fire `error` event ever. But I know `OutgoingMessage` is basically a `WritableStream` and as such prone to `error`.

Also, when I read this official [Node.js docs about Anatomy of an HTTP transaction](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/), it is recommended to handle errors on the Response Stream.

If yes, what scenarios will cause `error` event to fire up? Should I just swallow these errors silently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been wondering the exact same thing this week, and I can't really seem to find any straightforward answers.

I scoured through [Koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/application.js#L199) to see what they do, and it doesn't look like they ever attach an error handler to the res stream at all.

Whatever might cause that stream error must be rare, or doesn't crash your program like the Node tutorial suggests. If it did, Koa would be unusable, which does not seem to be the case since a lot of people use it.

I looked through other HTTP frameworks like Hapi and Express, but their codebases are so complicated I found it hard to draw a similar conclusion. :\

I also found [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2823-does-the-http-response-stream-need-error-event-handlers-in-node-js.htm) set of experiments from a few years ago that seem to indicate that Node's tutorial isn't quite lining up with Node's actual behavior:

> While this experimentation may not be an exhaustive look at all the things that can go wrong in network programming, the results here seem to indicate that an HTTP response stream will never emit an error event; or, at the very least, that such an error event will never crash the server. So, while you have to bind an "error" event handler to just about every other streams in Node.js, it would seem that you can safely assume the HTTP response stream will never error, no matter what happens. And, that even if the response stream closes, you can continue to write to it / pipe to it without consequence.

For my own project I'm just going to log the error somewhere, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Handling error is not required for streams or anything in NodeJS, but is good practice. There is even a concept: **error-first callbacks** in NodeJS and the first parameter in a callback is actually an error object.

Lets imagine case where you don't handle and error:

```
fs.readFile('./non_existing_file.json', (err, data) => {

  // here we don't handle the error
  // and if there is an error
  // the second parameter will be undefined

  let myDataObj = JSON.parse(data)
  ...more code...

})
```

Now we did not handled the the error and when trying to parse **undefined** we get an error which crashes our application. We need to manually start our application.

By handling the error:

```
fs.readFile('./some_file.json', (err, data) => {

  if(err) throw err
  // if there is an error
  // the rest of the function won't be executed

  let myDataObj = JSON.parse(data)
  ...more code...

})
```

Now this will log an error telling us what exactly went wrong and our application won't crash, it will just log the error.

It is not necessary to log the error, we just log it to help us debugging. Of course you can safely swallow it by replacing `if(err) throw err` with `if(err) return`

It is up to you to decide how to handle errors or to handle them at all. It is good thing to log them and even better to notify your users that something went wrong.

Comment: You're not wrong, but I'd call this answer a bit off topic. This question is specifically about what you should do with a stream error from the writable HTTP response stream. Obviously you can't notify the user in this scenario because the response stream would be closed.